# How to configure separately both consumer and producer spring boot app when using rabbitmq?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I watched a tutorial that explains how to integrate RabbitMQ into Spring Boot app. In the tutorial, the `ReceiveMessageHandler.java` (Consumer) and `SendMessageController.java` (Producer) classes were in the same project. I want to implement them in two different Spring Boot application. However I can't split the tutorial project into two consumer and producer project because of the `ConfigureRabbitMq` class. Because it is coupled both `ReceiveMessageHandler.java` (Consumer) and `SendMessageController.java` (Producer) classes.

How can I implement and configure two different cosnumer and producer Spring Boot application?

`ConfigureRabbitMq.java`

```
import com.example.demorabbitmq.rabbitmq.consumer.ReceiveMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConfigureRabbitMq {

    public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "mikeexchange2";
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "mikequeue2";


    @Bean
    Queue createQueue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue q, TopicExchange exchange){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(exchange).with("mike.#");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
            , MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter){
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(ReceiveMessageHandler handler){
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(handler, "handleMessage");
    }


}
```

`ReceiveMessageHandler.java` (Consumer)

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class ReceiveMessageHandler {

    public void handleMessage(String messageBody){
        log.info("HandleMessage!!!");
        log.info(messageBody);
    }

}
```

`SendMessageController.java` (Producer)

```
import com.example.demorabbitmq.rabbitmq.ConfigureRabbitMq;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SendMessageController {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public SendMessageController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @PostMapping("/send")
    public String sendMessage(@RequestParam String themessage){
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ConfigureRabbitMq.EXCHANGE_NAME,
                "mike.springmessages", themessage);
        return "We have sent a message! :" + themessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure RabbitMQ in both of the projects, however you DON'T need to create the following bean in Producer project's ConfigureRabbitMq.class :

```
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(ReceiveMessageHandler handler){
     return new MessageListenerAdapter(handler, "handleMessage");
}
```

Comment: However, If I use this bean in producer project, then how producer resolve the ReceiveMessageHandler class? Because it will be placed in only consumer project.

Comment: Okay, I see. However, if I remove this Bean from the producer project, it causes error like this: `Parameter 1 of method simpleMessageListenerContainer in com.example.producer.rabbitmq.ConfigureRabbitMq required a bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter' that could not be found.`

Comment: You don't need SimpleMessageListenerContainer bean as well, in your producer class right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it is worked, after removing SimpleMessageListenerContainer  bean .

Comment: I have a question, `createQueue`, `exchange` and `binding` beans should be placed both consumer and producer classes? or only one of them is enough?

Comment: I think createQueue would be optional for Consumer, however you can refer to the official documentation, that would clear your concepts https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-spring-amqp.html